# converting a string that contains an array into a json object

Tags: arrays, json, groovy, soapui

In SOAPUI requests return values in the form of strings, whatever they contain.
A request returns the following string at time t:

```
{satisfied=true, dynamic_href/properties/triggers, name=triggers, value={satisfied=true, dynamic_href/properties/triggers, name=triggers, value=[{type=DAILY, description=null, configuration={allXDays=1, time=08:10:29, timeProgramMode=TIME, startDate=2019-02-28}, id=guid], metadata={satisfied=true, href=/m2m/fim/metadata/items/com.hager.domovea.automation.sequence.Sequence/properties/triggers, name=null, description=null, type=null, classes=null, regex=null, min=null, max=null, step=null, enumeration=null, beanMetadata=null, readable=null, writable=null, eventable=null, asyncStatusPropertyName=null, attributes=null}, asyncStatusProperty=null}, metadata={satisfied=true, href=/m2m/fim/metadata/items/com.hager.domovea.automation.sequence.Sequence/properties/triggers, name=null, description=null, type=null, classes=null, regex=null, min=null, max=null, step=null, enumeration=null, beanMetadata=null, readable=null, writable=null, eventable=null, asyncStatusPropertyName=null, attributes=null}, asyncStatusProperty=null}
```

at time t+1 the same request returns the following

```
{satisfied=true, dynamic_href/properties/triggers, name=triggers, value={satisfied=true, dynamic_href/properties/triggers, name=triggers, value=[{type=DAILY, description=null, configuration={allXDays=1, timeProgramMode=TIME, startDate=2019-02-28, time=08:10:29}, id=guid], metadata={satisfied=true, href=/m2m/fim/metadata/items/com.hager.domovea.automation.sequence.Sequence/properties/triggers, name=null, description=null, type=null, classes=null, regex=null, min=null, max=null, step=null, enumeration=null, beanMetadata=null, readable=null, writable=null, eventable=null, asyncStatusPropertyName=null, attributes=null}, asyncStatusProperty=null}, metadata={satisfied=true, href=/m2m/fim/metadata/items/com.hager.domovea.automation.sequence.Sequence/properties/triggers, name=null, description=null, type=null, classes=null, regex=null, min=null, max=null, step=null, enumeration=null, beanMetadata=null, readable=null, writable=null, eventable=null, asyncStatusPropertyName=null, attributes=null}, asyncStatusProperty=null}
```

I have to compare them to check that no property changed, however there is a subtle order change in the value array so direct string comparison is impossible.
When I try to use jsonSlurper to convert it so I could compare element by element, it raises an error.
I thought it would help me to parse my responses and compare easily.

I'm trying to find a way to parse high level properties (such as 'satisfied') but also nested properties such as value or metadata and the array at an even lower level ...

**EDIT**

Trying to parse with json slurper gives me the following error :

```
expecting '}' or ',' but got current char 's' with an int value of 115

The current character read is 's' with an int value of 115
expecting '}' or ',' but got current char 's' with an int value of 115
line number 1
index number 1
{satisfied=true, dynamic_href/properties/triggers, name=triggers, value={satisfied=true, dynamic_href/properties/triggers, name=triggers, value=[{type=DAILY, description=mon trigger, configuration={allXDays=1, action=switchOn, time=16:01:02, timeProgramMode=TIME, startDate=2018-04-11}, id=guid], metadata={satisfied=true, href=/m2m/fim/metadata/items/com, hager, domovea, automation, homestatus, HomeStatus/properties/triggers, name=null, description=null, type=null, classes=null, regex=null, min=null, max=null, step=null, enumeration=null, beanMetadata=null, readable=null, writable=null, eventable=null, asyncStatusPropertyName=null, attributes=null}, asyncStatusProperty=null}, metadata={satisfied=true, href=/m2m/fim/metadata/items/com, hager, domovea, automation, homestatus, HomeStatus/properties/triggers, name=null, description=null, type=null, classes=null, regex=null, min=null, max=null, step=null, enumeration=null, beanMetadata=null, readable=null, writable=null, eventable=null, asyncStatusPropertyName=null, attributes=null}, asyncStatusProperty=null}
.^
```

Comment: "When I try to use jsonSlurper to convert it so I could compare element by element, it raises an error" - It would be helpful if you showed what you have tried, and shared what ever error is raised.

Comment: In the JSON shown in the recent edit, there are 6 opening curly braces (`{`) and only 5 closing braces (`}`).

Comment: The JSON slurper is complaining because it is being asked to parse invalid JSON.

Comment: Most likely the thing you want to compare is not a string, but something along the lines turns it into a string (e.g. a `.toString()`) -- maybe even your own code (check with `.dump()` on your data). You are better off preventing string-ification (as it's usually not a proper serialization format) and deal with the actual object. If your upstream server really only returns a string, then have a look at the content-type the server sends.  Then use a library, that can read that format.

Comment: sure, ReadyAPI does stringify the result... when it returns a value from a request, if you want to use it from another testCase you can only get in in String format (unless there is a trick that I'm not aware ?). This can be really a problem sometimes :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{satisfied=true, dynamic_href/properties/triggers, name=triggers, value={satisfied=true, dynamic_href/properties/triggers, name=triggers, value=[{type=DAILY, description=null, configuration={allXDays=1, timeProgramMode=TIME, startDate=2019-02-28, time=08:10:29}, id=guid], metadata={satisfied=true, href=/m2m/fim/metadata/items/com.hager.domovea.automation.sequence.Sequence/properties/triggers, name=null, description=null, type=null, classes=null, regex=null, min=null, max=null, step=null, enumeration=null, beanMetadata=null, readable=null, writable=null, eventable=null, asyncStatusPropertyName=null, attributes=null}, asyncStatusProperty=null}, metadata={satisfied=true, href=/m2m/fim/metadata/items/com.hager.domovea.automation.sequence.Sequence/properties/triggers, name=null, description=null, type=null, classes=null, regex=null, min=null, max=null, step=null, enumeration=null, beanMetadata=null, readable=null, writable=null, eventable=null, asyncStatusPropertyName=null, attributes=null}, asyncStatusProperty=null}
```

There are mismatched curly braces in that String.  There are 6 `{` and 5 `}`.  The parser can't deal with that.

**EDIT**

2 other issues are that the keys are not quoted and there are `=` where there should be `:`.  There is also stuff like `... , dynamic_href/properties/triggers, ...` which is not valid JSON.

Comment: Also the keys aren't quoted.  Is that OK?  I haven't actually tried...I always see things like `{'hello': 1}` but I guess I don't know if it's required.

Comment: @Daniel There is a "lax" mode, that would allow that, if enabled. Not that it would help here...

Comment: @cfrick Interesting, thanks for the info!  And glad that 'lax' isn't lax enough to ignore missing braces... :-)

Comment: Well, I thought that there was no intermediate processing but there actually is some. You're right, the content has some missing braces ! I went through all the process again and managed to correct it so, now, I have a correct formatting of the output and json parsing works as expected. thanks !

Comment: @A.Joly "...now, I have a correct formatting of the output and json parsing works as expected" - Awesome!  I am glad that you got it worked out.